# Magento Shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

Anyone can help..

Whats the possible issue for this error:

https://www.screencast.com/t/9ihnF6WdP

Thanks.

Comment: Check var/log there you can find details for this Error.

Comment: Can I delete those logs there?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the form key is also going in post data under n/w tab in developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your  element: `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` in cart.phtml